# Issue with notes going over the time signature

Tags: theory, piano, notation, sheet-music

[image]

I'm transferring this score to Finale, am almost at the end of it, and I'm really confused as to how this works. There are 16th notes between the 8th notes, probably done with another layer, but then in the treble clef, it looks like there are notes that go after the bass part, but if that were the case (it's in 4/4 time btw), then it would take up more than the measure. Am I missing something here? Is this a type of formatting I'm not aware of?

Comment: the 16th in the r.h.  are together with the 8th notes of the l.h. Do you just want to correct the notation or do you want to know what is going wrong?

Comment: Pretty much what's going wrong; I'm just copying it because the original's formatting sucks

Comment: and what was the kind of original format? midi? mus? XML?

Comment: Ah, I meant that it took up 7 pages, not the actual file format, so I'm trying to shorten it to 2 or 4 cuz there are some measures that take up a whole line just by themselves for not much practical reason. The original file format was in pdf, so no way to convert it or anything.

Comment: So this sentence is confusing to me: *I'm transferring this score to Finale, almost at the end of it,* You just wonder how the beats and notes are meant to be?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: first you say you want to transfer this sheet to finale then you say there' s no way to convert it or anything ...

Comment: I meant there's no way to do it with a converter. If you were to try to open a pdf in Finale or convert it to musx, it wouldn't work. I am transferring it manually by putting the notes in.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what piece are you transferring?

Comment: [Lilium, arranged by Theishter](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tu249xQP6iMe17btjUdXsyrj7kfOe1Jt/view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might an error and the 16th notes are 32nd notes.
Or the 16ths might be tuplets.
I'd notate it like this in the former case:
[image]

... and like this in the latter case:

[image]

Comment: The latter does seem to be the issue, as [the beams match up](https://i.imgur.com/JkeEbOV.png) as in the original score

Answer (score 3):

Considering your other question ([24 16th notes in a 4/4 measure; Tuplets?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/102080/2257)), I suspect that the alignment here is correct, and that these aren't true 16th notes but rather triplets.  That would mean that the first part of each triplet should be a sixteenth rest, which would of course be aligned with the bass eighth notes, and that those rests are not shown for some reason.

Comment: Actually that would make a lot more sense, since they are in between the eight notes, and they would have to be aligned with the eight notes for that to work as regular sixteenth notes like in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the 8th note rests in both the treble and bass clefs on the downbeat the first 16th and 8th should line up. After that every other 16th should line up with an 8th note. You can also keep each hand in their respective staff by changing clef or using 8ba or 8va if you choose.

The blue lines indicate notes that happen simultaneously:

[image]

Comment: Ahh ok that males sense then

Comment: I’m curious, is your image from the reference score or Finale’s interpretation? As is its confusing, at first glance you would think the 16ths are in between the 8ths.

Comment: The score was exported from finale to a pdf but the one who arranged it didn't provide a Finale file.

Comment: I’m sure you can make it better, good luck!

Comment: @Shidouuu given your [other question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/102080/2257), it's possible (or rather likely) that these are actually triplets with missing sixteenth rests, and that the alignment is therefore correct.

Comment: @phoog If that’s the case there should be 16th rests before each pair of 16th notes.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy that's correct, and if your hypothesis is correct then there should be different alignment.  There are many things in this world that _should be_ but _are not._  In support of my hypothesis, I note that it's easy to find examples of triplet notation where the copyist or engraver obviously took the approach that being precisely correct leads to notation that is too busy and difficult to read.  It is harder to find examples where the copyist or engraver got the alignment consistently wrong.

Comment: @phoog To me it doesn’t look like any triplet notation I’ve ever seen but regardless of whether or not they are triplets it is poorly notated. It would have been much easier and more clear to put the entire right hand in the upper staff and the entire left in the lower staff and use clef changes or octave up or down symbols in each staff. The rhythm in the right hand would have been clearly shown in that case.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Indeed.  I was not aware of the scope of that problem until I started following this site, but now it is glaringly obvious.  Even before I joined here, though, I've seen occasional self-published works by supposedly well-trained composers with basic notation errors.

Comment: @phoog Sorry, I deleted the comment you just responded to, I didn’t want to seem like I was going on a rant, lol. It’s too easy to make good looking music these days, it’s a little harder to make it accurate. I do respect your opinion regarding the triplets though. Guess we’ll never know!

Answer (score 0):

Both systems have an eighth rest on the first beat.  The notes are on different layers. The most simple solution is: just give in the notes a new, 4 voices in 4 different layers.

alternately try:

1.

-> explode music (utilities) and see what happens:

->  choose different colours (view and select layer colours)

if necessarily edit the notation

-> implode

or try

2. menu Edit

-> edit measure attributes

-> Position notes (using beat-chart spacing -> according to time signature)

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned that the image posted was not from the document I was editing, but from an exported pdf (which was originally from Finale)

Answer (score 0):

So if this is from a pdf the original arranger has notated both hands in the bass clef (beat 1,2) and then both hands in the treble clef (3,4). This print was probably by "hidden" rests.

If you scan this sheet it will cause problems but if you edit this bar by hand you can solve them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the program used to typeset the original score had issues with the alignment of distinct (sticks up vs sticks down) voices. I've modified the supplied snap to show how it *should* have looked:

[image]