# 24 16th notes in a 4/4 measure; Tuplets?

Tags: theory, piano, notation, sheet-music

[image]

They're not labeled tuplets, but they probably are since there cannot be 24 16th notes in a 4/4 measure. They don't appear to be a standard triplet though since it still doesn't fit (with each triplet equal to 2 16th's).

Comment: Shidouuu - please don't edit the answer into the post. I have rolled back to your previous version to take that out.

Comment: Neither a time signature nor a barline in sight - graphic snippet can be improved.

Comment: Can't really do anything about that since the last time signature change is several measures back. I've already stated it in the title

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are sextuplets - 6 semiquavers in the time of 4.  They probably thought it was obvious enough, since they are grouped clearly in 4 crochet beats.